# Как правильно получать данные с бекенда с реализацией rxjava/retrofit/room/cache in memory?

Tags: android, кэширование, rxjava, room

заметил, что данный способ не совсем верный: если впервые получить данные с сервера, потом перезайти в приложение, возвратятся данные из локальной базы. А в это время данные на сервере могут обновиться, получается, всегда несвежие данные будут видны

```
public Maybe<List<Review>> getReviewsByProductId(int id) {
    Observable<List<Review>> remote = remoteDataSource.getReviewsByProductId(id)
            .doOnNext(reviews -> localDataSource.insertReviews(reviews))
            .doOnNext(reviews -> cacheDataSource.putReviews(id, reviews));
    Observable<List<Review>> local = localDataSource.getReviewsByProductId(id)
            .filter(reviews -> !reviews.isEmpty())
            .doOnNext(reviews -> cacheDataSource.putReviews(id, reviews));

    Observable<List<Review>> cache = cacheDataSource.getReviewsByProductId(id);

    return Observable.concat(cache, local, remote)
            .firstElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Как правильно реализовать такое? 
1) получить данные из сети;
2) при следующих обращениях брать из кеша
3) если сети нет, из базы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понимаю это примерно следующим образом. В гайде говорится об едином источнике верных (true) данных (назовём доверенным источником). Идея лежит в том что вы свои вьюшки подписываете на обновление данных в базе и выводите только их пользователю, а бекенд обновляете по мере необходимости, например при входе в приложение вы обновляете например категории товаров. А остальные данные обновляете по мере необходимости.

Кеш, что это и зачем, принципе идея использования кеша лежит в том чтобы часто не бегать за данными на сервак так как это очень затратное действие по таким ограниченным данным как: мегабайты интернета. И нужен он только в том случае когда вы не используете что-то подобное базе данных ибо за каждым пуком вам прийдётся дергать сервер, а здесь вас уже может рубануть и CloudFlare как жёсткого дедосника. Но это не означает что только для этого мы используем второе место использования кеша это чтения из диска, это тоже лучше кешировать, ну и третий вариант, большой объём информации получаемый из БД, и их нужно постоянно изменять. В таком решении нам нужно уже использовать доверительным источником данных КЕШ,  в иных случаях я использую доверительным источником БД.

[Тут гайд есть на ру.](https://habr.com/ru/post/456256/)